# add a string to a string variable python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

How do I concatenate a variable and a string in Python?

```
cases = ['087360','095140']

for case in cases:
    case+'biofile' = pandas.read_csv(case+'/InputFiles/BioSave.csv')
```

I want this to store '087360biofile' and '095140biofile'.

Comment: You can't name variables like that. Use a dictionary instead. `my_dict =
 {case+'biofile': pandas.read_csv(case+'/InputFiles/BioSave.csv') for case in cases}`. Then access your elements like `my_dict['087360biofile']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is a dictionary good?

```
biofile = {}

for case in cases:
    biofile[case] =  pandas.read_csv(case+'/InputFiles/BioSave.csv')
```

Then you can access it as:

```
biofile['087360']
```

Comment: "Is a dictionary good?" Yes. :)

Answer (score 4):

You almost never want to do this, but if you *really* do - all variables in python are stored in dictionaries. You can directly access these dictionaries, for example the dictionary for local variables.

```
for case in cases:
    locals()[case+'biofile'] = pandas.read_csv(case+'/InputFiles/BioSave.csv')
```

But unfortunately this turns out to be useless! Not because of how we assigned it, but because the name starts with a number, which means we can't access it (except through the dictionary), because the python parser will try and split off the number as something separate. We could instead go with

```
for case in cases:
    locals()['biofile'+case] = pandas.read_csv(case+'/InputFiles/BioSave.csv')
```

Which would give you a valid python name (e.g `biofile087360`).

But it's much more natural (and probably what you want to do) to just put them in a dictionary

```
biofiles = {}
for case in cases:
    biofiles[case] = pandas.read_csv(case+'/InputFiles/BioSave.csv')
```

Comment: plus 1 for pointing out that variables can't start with numbers.